# Looking to add wired connection between two computers on the same existing wireless connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, crossover

I'm currently trying to set up a wired LAN connection between two computers on the same wireless network. Ideally, I would want the two computers to still be connected to the internet and other network devices, but with an additional wired connection between them for high speed file transfers. Here's a crudely drawn image of what I'm hoping for:

[image]

Currently, I have the wireless network configured as normal, standard 192.168 etc. I have each wired network interface configured to 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2, subnet mask 255.0.0.0 and everything else blank. The computers connect to the internet, and can connect to eachother over the wireless LAN, but for example if I ping 10.0.0.2 from the first PC or 10.0.0.1 from the second, there is no connection. Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks.

Comment: What OS are the computers running? Does the OS report the link status as being up? (Not the interface status.) Have you tried a regular cable instead? Do you have any sort of VPN running? Have you tried using a longer prefix length, e.g. netmask 255.255.255.0, to rule out overlapping routes?

Comment: Both are running windows 10. Both OS report the link status as up. I have not tried a regular cable instead. There are no VPNs running, but both computers have VPNs installed. I have tried using a longer prefix length.

Comment: You need to add routes to the `10.x` computers.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if answering my own question is the proper thing to do in this situation, but I ended up finding the solution. The configuration I stated in the question ended up being fine, but I had neglected to make the wired connection private (or configure local network access for public connections). Basically, I guess that means the problem was with Windows 10 firewall, but really my own neglect.

Because nothing is ever that simple, there were still problems with routing (particularly with any built in windows file sharing). For anyone else who ends up with this issue, I had to take the additional step of blocking local communication between the two computers using my router's firewall. After that, it seems to now work as imagined, with local communication between the two PCs strictly wired and everything else wireless.